# PowerShell/CMD command to map metadata from one set of files to another, in different drives

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, powershell, cmd.exe

So I have a set of files in one drive (C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\new) with just .m4v files.

I want to copy the metadata of files in a folder in another drive (S:\new2) to those in the "new" folder. "new2" has files in .mp4, but the files in "new" and "new2" have the exact same filenames.

I used HandBrake to convert all files in "new2" from 1080p to 720p, and saved them in the "new" folder, however they all lost their metadata like modified time and created time.

So what could I do to transfer the metadata? I've seen it's possible to use FFmpeg to map metadata from one file to another, but I don't know what to do with entire folders in separate drives.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -i out.mp4 -map 1 -map_metadata 0 -c copy fixed.mp4
```

The command above is what would be used to map metadata between two files. "in" is the file before conversion, "out" is the file after conversion, and "fixed" would be the "out" file with "in"'s metadata after it has been mapped.

Any help is appreciated! I could use either a powershell or a cmd command.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ffmpeg`, but assuming it has the ability to *write* the metadata (**PowerShell** can only read), you'll want to make that the processing statement inside a `ForEach` loop. It would be helpful if you edited your question to include example `ffmpeg` command(s)....

Comment: Welcome to SU. SU/SO, has rules: [How to ask](https://superuser.com/questions/how-to-ask), [Provide MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) --- [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) --- [Don't ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) --- [Proper Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) --- [Why not upload images of code/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) --- [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: It's the app that controls access to its metadata. You need to understand the 'Object Model' and get to the attributes it will allow you to change. What did you search for? Show you code attempts. [powershell 'read mp4 metadata'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell+%27read+mp4+metadata%27&t=h_&ia=web), [powershell 'change mp4 metadata'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell+%27change+mp4+metadata%27&t=h_&ia=web),[powershell 'update mp4 metadata'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=powershell+%27update+mp4+metadata%27&t=h_&ia=web)

Comment: @KeithMiller you're right, I will edit the post to include the FFmpeg command that I saw posted before here in SU.

Comment: So is that command altering the existing files in "new" or creating modified copies of them; with the originals subsequently deleted?

Comment: It is creating new ones, and not deleting any. All it does is take the existing files in new, copy the metadata from new2, and then make modified copies.

Comment: So, are the new files getting a modified name or going into a different folder?

Comment: In the example code that I put in the description, the new files are all within the same folder, and theyre getting a new name. This isn't what I want though. I simply want to copy the metadata of the files in "new2" into the files in "new" (I know this is a very confusing naming scheme I chose), both of which have the same filenames.

Comment: But, with the command you've given, you are creating a new file, and then you'll want it to replace the file lacking metadata. And since you can't have identical filenames in the same directory, they have to be created in a different directory and subsequently copied over the original; or created with a modified name, followed by deletion of original and re-naming of copy. Make sense?

Comment: Yeah, makes sense. Ideally I would like to have all the new modified files in a separate directory. But changing their names works too.

Comment: @KeithMiller powershell of course can write metadata because it has full access to the Win32 API and can call any C or C# functions. That means anything explorer can do, powershell can also do. Some examples [Can you set Details for Videos with Powershell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54522795/995714), [Use PowerShell to edit a file's metadata (Details tab of a file in Windows file explorer)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64597009/995714)

Comment: True, perhaps I should have said no relatively easy, consistemt for all properties way...I.E. The write-eequivalent of the `ExtendedProperty` method...

Comment: @phuclv: The links you posted bear me out. The first has a solution for *some* file types with the aid of a 3rd party library, and the answers to the second echo my sentiments...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested, but I think this would do the trick:

```
$new  = 'C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\new'
$new2 = 'S:\new2'
$temp = ( mkdir "$env:tmp\$((Get-Date).Ticks)").FullName

$TroubleShoot = @'
MetaSource: "{0}"
MetaAbsent: "{1}"
Press any key to continue...
'@

Get-ChildItem -Path $new, $new2 -File |
  group BaseName |
  where Count -eq 2 | ForEach{
    $MetaSource = ( $_.Group | ? DirectoryName -eq $new2 ).FullName
    $MetaAbsent = ( $_.Group | ? DirectoryName -eq $new ).FullName
    $MetaFixed  = '{0}\{1}.mp4' -f $temp , $_.Name

    Read-Host ($TroubleShoot -f $MetaSource , $MetaAbsent )

    ffmpeg -i $MetaSource -i $MetaAbsent -map 1 -map_metadata 0 -c copy $MetaFixed
}
Copy-Item $temp\* $new -Force
Remove-Item $temp -Force
```

This code collects the file info from both directories, then [groups](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) on `BaseName` to pair them off. Then we get the `FullName` for each file, construct the desstination filename, and execute the `ffmpeg` command. After all new files are created, they're copied over the originals and the temp folder is deleted.

Comment: This might just work. I will test it now and come back to you. Thank you very much for all the help so far!

Comment: It seems that something didn't work. I mentioned this in the original description, but the original files end with .mp4, and the converted ones end with .m4v. The first error I got is `New-Item: C:\Users\anton\Desktop\batch.ps1:3
Line |
   3 |  $temp = ( mkdir $env:tmp\ffmpeg ).FullName
     |  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | An item with the specified name C:\Users\anton\AppData\Local\Temp\ffmpeg already exists.` and the second one I got for every file is `-i: No such file or directory`. Sorry for the terrible formatting btw!

Comment: When using the modified code, it seems $MetaSource and $MetaAbsent come up empty.

Comment: It seems that it worked this time! Thank you very much!